# Pass properties to React components with typescript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

I'm doing a project with React and typescript, but I'm not able to pass properties to a React component, this property is an array of custom elements, this element has 3 pieces of information, name, age and profession. Currently I just want the component to wrap the array and for each item, show an h1 with the name. This is the code:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react"

import { Button } from "../elements/Button/Button"
import { ContainerStyles } from "../elements/ContainerStyles/ContainerStyles"
import { GlobalStyles } from "../elements/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles"
import { Input } from "../elements/Input/Input"
import { Elements } from "../elements/Elements/Elements"

import axios from "axios";

export type personType = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    profession: string
}

export const Home = () => {

    const [InputName, setName] = useState<string>();
    const [InputAge, setInputAge] = useState<string>();
    const [Inputprofession, setInputProfession] = useState<string>();
    const [personNameToSearch, setPersonNameToSearch] = useState<string>();

    

    const [person, setPerson] = useState<Array<personType>>([]);


    const getName = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }

    const getAge = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputAge(e.target.value)

    }

    const getProfession = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputProfession(e.target.value)
    }

    const AddPerson = () => { // essa função está sendo ativada, mas está caindo no catch
        axios.post('http://localhost:3333/person/', {
            name: InputName,
            idade: InputAge,
            profissao: Inputprofession
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((response) => { 
            const message = response.message;
            if (message == 'Request failed with status code 500') {
                console.log('Ha informações faltando ou uma informação foi dada de forma incorreta')
            }
            
        }); 
    }

    const GetPersonsInfo = async () => {
        

        axios.get(`http://localhost:3333/person/${personNameToSearch}`, {}).then(
            function (response) {
                const name = response.data.name
                const idade = response.data.idade
                const profissao = response.data.profissao

                setPerson([...person, {
                    name: name,
                    age: idade,
                    profession: profissao
                }])

                
            }  
        );
            console.log(person)
        
    }

    const getPersonName = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setPersonNameToSearch(e.target.value)
    } 

    return(
        <>
            <GlobalStyles/>
            <ContainerStyles>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getName(e)} placeholder={"Nome:"}/>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getAge(e)} placeholder={"Idade:"}/>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getProfession(e)} placeholder={"Profissão:"}/>
                <Button onClick={() => AddPerson()}>Adicionar usuário</Button>
            </ContainerStyles>
            <ContainerStyles>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getPersonName(e)}/>
                <Button onClick={() =>  GetPersonsInfo()}>Mostrar Usuários</Button>
            </ContainerStyles>
        </>
    )
}
```

and:

```
import React from "react";
import { personType } from "../../pages/Home";


export const Elements = ( persons:Array<personType> ) => {
     return ( 
        <>
            {persons.map((person: personType) => <h1 {person.name}></h1>)};
        </>   
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you'd better pass a single object into functional component, so this approach should work:

```
interface personType {
  name: string;
}

export const Elements = (props: { persons: Array<personType> }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.persons.map((person: personType) => <h1> {person.name}</h1>)};
    </>
  );
};

export const Test = () => {
  var personsArray: personType[] = [];
  return (<Elements persons={personsArray} />)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the name to an h1 as a prop. Just use `<h1>{person.name}</h1>` instead of what you have there.

You also are using the wrong format for props. Wrap `persons:Array<personType>` in file 2 in curly brackets.

Lastly, you will need to make sure you are rendering the elements component. If you are not rendering it, it doesn't do anything. When you render it, do it like this:

```
// replace personsArray with the name of your array
<Elements persons={personsArray}/>
```